# Firestore / React is unsubscribe necessary in componentWillUnmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router, google-cloud-firestore

I have a component that is at a particular route:

```
<Route path='/route-path' component={MyComponent} />
```

In this component all of my firestore listeners are created in componentDidMount like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
   var unsubscribe = db.collection(name)
       .where("query", "==", false)
       .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
          // do something
       })
}
```

Is it necessary to unsubscribe this listener if the route changes? Something like:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  unsusbscribe() // from componentDidMount
}
```

or is this handled automatically by route changes, i.e. the websocket closes the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firestore SDK has no implicit knowledge about ReactJS and/or its lifecycle events.

You'll need to unsubscribe in your own code. It is not done automatically.