# How to use firebase functions with web app on front end?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The thing I want is to detect the change is the collection `"users"`. But not all the change only one type of change. I want to trigger a callback when a new document is added to the collection.

I am really new to firebase. The thing which I think I need is firebase cloud functions. But on the docs, I don't see any way to add `firebase-functions` and `firebase-tools` in HTML. If we can't use firebase-functions without node so kindly tell the correct way to detect the addition of new document inside firebase...

**Note:** I am also using typescript so please consider that it will not throw any error and give correct autocompletion(if there is a way to use firebase-functions on the browser)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [correct way to use firestore onSnapShot with react redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49733377/correct-way-to-use-firestore-onsnapshot-with-react-redux)

Answer (score 2):

The way to listen to a collection on the client side is with `onSnapshot`. This will notify you of every change, so if you only care about particular changes you can compare before and after and only run your code when the part you care about changes.

```
let prevSnapshot;

firebase
  .app()
  .firestore()
  .collection('users')
  .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    if (!prevSnapshot || snapshot.docs.length !== prevSnapshot.docs.length) {
      // this is either the first snapshot, or the number of documents has changed.
      prevSnapshot = snapshot;
      // Do whatever you need to do
    }
  });
```

Comment: How to get the which new doc is added without looping through all of the docs or is there no method for that?